# PHP Template: File Upload Handler

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop some templates for common `PHP` tasks I've been dealing with. One of which is a general file upload handler.
So far I'm using the following reusable code which seems to be working fine without any noticeable bug:

```
<?php

    if ( !isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        goto page_content;}

    if ( $_FILES['file_upload']['error']===4 ) {
        echo 'No file uploaded';
        goto page_content;}

    if ( $_FILES['file_upload']['error']===1 || $_FILES['file_upload']['error']===2 ) {
        echo 'File exceeds maximum size limit';
        goto page_content;}

    if ( $_FILES['file_upload']['error']!==0 ) {
        echo 'Failed to upload the file';
        goto page_content;}

    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']) ) {
        echo 'Failed to upload the file';
        goto page_content;}

    require_once('imageResize.php');
    $err = imageResize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], 'random.png' );
    if ( $err !== 0 ) {
        echo 'Invalid image format';
        goto page_content;}

    echo 'Image uploaded successfully';

    page_content:
?>
<form action="filename.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Additional file `imageResize.php`:

```
<?php
    // image resize
    function imageResize($source, $target){

        $size = getimagesize($source);
        if ($size === false) {return 1;} // invalid image format

        $sourceImg = @imagecreatefromstring(@file_get_contents($source));
        if ($sourceImg === false) {return 2;} //invalid image format

        $width = imagesx($sourceImg);
        $height = imagesy($sourceImg);
        $sidelenght = min($width,$height);
        $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
        imagecopyresampled($targetImg, $sourceImg, 0, 0, ($width-$sidelenght)/2, ($height-$sidelenght)/2, 100, 100, $sidelenght, $sidelenght);
        imagedestroy($sourceImg);
        imagepng($targetImg, $target);
        imagedestroy($targetImg);

        return 0;           
    }
?>
```

Some main characteristics of this code are:

- provides messages for the most common errors that can happened during the upload process
- it allows the client to upload an image file up to 1Mb size
- resizes all images to a standard 100x100 px size
- save all images to a standard PNG format

**Questions**

1. Does this code safe? Or are there any vulnerability that could be exploited by an malicious client? In this case, how to solve it?
2. To avoid several nested `IF-THEN-ELSE` conditions (which can become hard to read), I'm currently using `GOTO` (which can become a bad control structure practice). Is there a better alternative?
3. Any other idea to improve it?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is what you're looking for

Comment: @Samuel Is it possible to transfer it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would just copy+paste it on there. They are a pretty nice community, and every time you have *working* code which you think can be improved they are extremely helpful.

Comment: @Samuel _"I would just copy+paste it on there."_ Besides that, I would also have to delete this one at SO.

Comment: Not necessarily... You don't *have* to. You can just use this for future reference, and if a similar question comes up share it on there.

Comment: @Samuel Posts can be migrated between [se] community and sister sites. No need for creating cross-site duplicates. Just flag the post as off-topic with custom reason that `it should get migrated to [codereview.se]`, which will get converted to a comment as: "it should get migrated to [codereview.se]". Moderators and other users agreeing to your flag will make it happen :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it now has a cross site duplicate at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197826/12240 (and is better suited there).

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks... I actually didn't know about that, learning something new everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, look into putting this code into functions (maybe even a class), and instead of `goto`'s just use `return`. This will allow you to better structure and separate logic where it needs to be separated.

Look at this example:

```
function upload_image($file)
{
  if( $err = check_error($file['error']) ) return $err;
  if( !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) ) return 'Failed to upload the file';
  $resize = imageResize($file['tmp_name'], 'random.png');
  if( $resize !== 0 )
  {
    return 'Invalid image format';
  }

  return true;
}
```

For error checking look into using the `switch` function. It will be more organized (in my opinion).

I would also check for the numerical upload errors in a separate function, this will allow for the individual action to be easily distinguished.

```
function check_error($err)
{
  if($err === 0)
  {
    return false; // no errors
  }
  $response = false;
  switch($err)
  {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      $response = 'File exceeds maximum size limit';
      break;
    case 4:
      $response = 'No file uploaded';
      break;
    default:
      $response = 'Unkown error';
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Then just call the function and display an error at the top if any:

```
$upload = upload_image($_FILE['file_upload']);
if( $upload === true ):
  echo 'Image uploaded successfully!';
else:
  echo $upload;
?>
<form action="filename.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
  <input type="file" name="file_upload" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Totally agree (code into functions, switch and numerical upload errors). Helpful insights. Thks!

Comment: Although I see your point and liked most of your ideas, there are still some issues with your code: 1) missing equal sign at `$response = 'Failed to upload the file';`, 2) missing equal sign at `$response 'File exceeds maximum size limit';`, .....

Comment: 3) try to execute PHP file and upload any standar file, you will always get the following output: `Failed to upload the file`

Comment: 4) `case 0`: If the value is **identical** to 0, then there is no error and the file uploaded with success ([Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)).

Comment: 5) since the `switch-case` is not set to do identical comparisons (as in the original post), it is another source of bugs.

Comment: @MarkMessa I just noticed the syntax errors (as well as the `case 0`). I updated my answer. I am not sure I understand your third point, though.

Comment: _"I updated my answer."_ Just for the records, there are still some issues: even if you upload nothing (or simply open the PHP file), there will be the error message `Unkown error`.